# SQL Server Agent - Do not show job step details and column headers in output file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent, csv

I have a SQL Server Agent job which runs a select statement on a schedule and appends results to a CSV file

(Right click the job --> properties --> advanced and then adding a file path to the output file location)

This is great except the output it generates displays

```
Job 'MyJobName' : Step1, 'Step Name' : Began executing YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS
```

as well as the column headers throughout the file (it adds this with each append)

Is there a way to not output the Job name / step details and column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do this with SQLCMD**

**Query**

*remember to add nocount so it does not add the rows affected to the file*

```
sqlcmd -Q"set nocount on; select * from sys.databases;"  -S localhost -D master -o  "c:\temp\test3.csv"
```

**Your job step needs to be SQLCMD however**
[image]

**The file**

[image]

**Part of the output**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Randi's approach

If using `POWERSHELL` is an option, you can change the job type to `POWERSHELL` and use `INVOKE-SQLCMD`.

A *possible* downside to this approach is because `ConvertTo-CSV` automatically surrounds output columns with double quotes.  The follow script handles the elimination of ALL double quotes and also removes the header from the results.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "." -Query "Select name from sys.databases where Database_ID <=4" | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % {$_ -replace '"',''} | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Out-File ("C:\Test\test.txt") -Append -Force -Encoding ascii
```

Running the SQL Agent job twice outputs the following for me due to using `-Append`

```
master
tempdb
model
msdb
master
tempdb
model
msdb
```

Comment: I like this aswell, but isn't the powershell job step kinda buggy? I mostly use cmd and call powershell from there.

Comment: @RandiVertongen - I _personally_ haven't encountered any issues using the Powershell job type, but I would not say I have used it _extensively_.  Testing would definitely be important.  My answer was an attempt to show how to remove the column headings from the output.